# Set zorder for the labels (vertex_text) in graph_tool

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw, graph-tool

I have a case in which `vertex_text` is hidden behind the one of the vertices (indicated by the red square in the image below). I have drawn this network using `graph_tool`'s circular layout (`minimize_nested_blockmodel_dl`).

[image]

In the `graph_tool`s docs (https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html), I did not find any way to set the `zorder` for the `vertex_text`.

I wonder if setting zorders for elements is possible in `graph_tool`. I would like to know if there is any workaround for this, while keeping the plot and the labels as they are i.e. same size, layout and locations.

If this is useful, for reference, here's are the vertex related parameters I used that went into the `draw` module:

```
vertex_text=[list of labels],
vertex_fill_color=[list of colors],
valpha=1,
vertex_size=10,
vertex_pen_width=0,
vertex_text_position=-2,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `vorder` parameter, which determines the relative order with which nodes and their labels are drawn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tiago! About `vertex_order`/`vorder` parameter, how should set it to draw all nodes first and then labels? Some more details would be very helpful.

Comment: Or maybe simply point me to one of the examples in the docs where this has been done(?). I will try to figure out of from example/s. (In fact, I learnt `graph_tool` mostly from the excellent examples in the docs.)

Comment: It is not currently possible to draw the nodes and the labels in different order, they are always drawn together. But you can order the nodes in arbitrary ways, and this is what the ``vorder`` parameter does.